# Calculate responsive margin for responsive fixed image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a template showcasing soccer players stats.

On the left there is the .picture of the player. It's fixed and the height is 100% of the window. Its width increases or decreases when you reduce the height of the window.

On the right, you should find the players stats and biography. It all fit in the div .block-left. The width should be 100% minus the player .picture width.

For now, the only way to showcase it is to increase the value of margin-left with the same value as the .picture width.

Here lies the problem, .picture width is always changing depending on your screen resolution, so should the margin-left of .block-content.

I can't find a practical way to do this. Maybe jQuery?

The template is available here : http://bettercheckthekids.com/pirlo/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a popular design but yes you can do it with jQuery using window resize event.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
      var imgWidth = $(".picture img").width();
      $(".block-left").css("margin-left", imgWidth);
});
```

Comment: Vahid, I implemented the script but it is not working. The console doesn't point to anything wrong. Do you have any what is not working on my side?